# How to find the number of hours that is part of a start and end date period based on conditions in r

Tags: r, date, datetime, timestamp

I have two tables, First table with columns - ID, Start_Date, End_Date Second table with columns - Day_of_Week, Start_Time, End_Time

```
      ID     Start_Date_Time       End_Date_Time
1 ABC123 2019-01-05 16:00:00 2019-01-07 20:00:00
2 XYZ123 2019-01-06 05:00:00 2019-01-13 05:00:00
3 XYZ456 2019-01-08 19:00:00 2019-01-13 12:00:00
```

And

```
      ID      Day StartTime EndTime
1 ABC123 Saturday     13:00   18:00
2 XYZ123   Sunday      0:00    6:00
3 XYZ456  Tuesday      0:00   12:00
```

I need a Resultant column in the first table which captures the number of hours within the Start_Date and End_Date based on the condition in the second table. In this case the result should be

```
ID        Start_Date          End_Date           Timeline_Hours
ABC123    01/05/2019 16:00    01/07/2019 20:00        2
XYZ123    01/06/2019 5:00     01/13/2019 5:00         6
XYZ456    01/08/2019 19:00    01/13/2019 12:00        0
```

For the first record: ABC123 - Number of hours withing the Start_Date and End_date based on the condition is 2 Hours.

Reason -  Date starts from Staurday 16:00 (4PM) and ends on Monday 20:00 (8PM), Condition in the second table says Saturday 13:00 to 18:00 so overlap is 2 Hours ( from 16:00 to 18:00)

Similarly second one has duration of more than a week and overlap for the first week is 1 Hour (from 5:00 to 6:00) and for the second week it is 5 Hours (from 0:00 to 5:00)

For third one no overlap so 0 Hour.

Can this be done in R?

Thanks
Nagaraj

---

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC123", "XYZ123", "XYZ456"), Start_Date_Time = structure(c(1546675200, 
        1546722000, 1546945200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
        End_Date_Time = structure(c(1546862400, 1547326800, 1547352000
        ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
            -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC123", "XYZ123", "XYZ456"), Day = c("Saturday", 
        "Sunday", "Tuesday"), StartTime = c("13:00", "0:00", "0:00"), 
        EndTime = c("18:00", "6:00", "12:00")), row.names = c(NA, 
            -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"

#generate all hours with df2
DT <- df1[, {
    x <- seq(min(as.IDate(Start_Date_Time)), max(as.IDate(End_Date_Time)), by="1 day")
    .(Date=x, Day=weekdays(x))
    }][
        df2, on=.(Day), nomatch=0L]
hoursDT <- DT[, .(ID, END_HR=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(paste(Date, StartTime), format=fmt) + 60*60,
        as.POSIXct(paste(Date, EndTime), format=fmt),
        by="1 hour")), 
    seq_len(nrow(DT))]

#count number of overlapping hours by joining the prev data.table with df1
df1[, Timeline_Hours := 
    hoursDT[.SD, on=.(ID, END_HR>Start_Date_Time, END_HR<=End_Date_Time), by=.EACHI, .N]$N
]
```

output for `df1`:

```
       ID     Start_Date_Time       End_Date_Time Timeline_Hours
1: ABC123 2019-01-05 16:00:00 2019-01-07 20:00:00              2
2: XYZ123 2019-01-06 05:00:00 2019-01-13 05:00:00              6
3: XYZ456 2019-01-08 19:00:00 2019-01-13 12:00:00              0
```